# Visual studio Code Node.js Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using json-server, javascript in visual studio code. I have installed lodash too (globally, and locally), and started coding. I had no problems for days, but now I get this error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

The code I wrote in my JavaScript file is this:

```js
const lodash = require('lodash');
```

Comment: When does this error occur? On start? On a specific event?

Comment: It appears on start

Comment: Did you do `npm init`? Do you see a file called package.json in the same directory?